# memory allocation, distribution and caching using C - Memcached

Tags: c, caching, memcached

Although I am a casual reader, this is my first post.

I am interested in learning about memory allocation, distribution and caching using C. I have a good understanding of the language although I haven't created large projects in C. I have experience in large projects in other languages (PHP, C++ & Matlab for mathematical modelling). I am studying all the relevant bibliography in order to feel confident. Just to get an idea in order to get an idea about my interests, my level of knowledge and help you guide me, some of the books I have in my shelves are the following:

1. The C programming language , Kernigham/Ritchie
2. C A reference manual, Harbioson/Steele
3. The unix programming environment, Kerningham/Pike
4. Advanced programming in the unix environment, Stevens/Rago
5. Advanced unix programming, Rochkind

In order to get a start in these subjects I decided to start exploring the code of [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Is there any link that could help me understand the main idea behind the Memcached project and how should I start studying it?
What are your suggestions?

I have downloaded the source code but I don't know if I should start from file foo or foo1 or ...
I was looking for a website/blog that gives some guidance in order to understand the code, but no luck.

Any other suggestions in order to study these topics (memory allocation, distribution and caching)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Here](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) is a great overview of how a typical memory allocator (Doug Lea's) is implemented on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Any C program starts executing in the `main()` function, and I don't expect Memcached to be an exception<sup>*</sup>. When getting to know a new C code base, it's often a good idea to find `main()`, and trace the program's execution from there.

The `#include`s in the C file that contains `main()` will often give good clues of the program's top-level architecture.

<sup>*</sup> One notable exception might be Windows, which uses `WinMain()` as the entry point. Bleh.